# from editor assignment pending to "Reviews Completed"

Tags: research-process, journals, paper-submission

I submitted a paper to one of the Springer Journals through Editorial Manager almost 2 months back. The status changed from "editor assignment pending" to  "Reviews Completed" since past three days. Can anybody suggest what does it actually mean ? D

Comment: All reviewers have submitted their reviews.

Comment: is it normal to get "Reviews Completed"  Without going on "under reviewing" ?

Comment: Assuming this is a properly refereed journal (why else would you submit to it, after all), the most likely explanation is that the editor forgot to update the status when he had obtained reviewers.

Comment: Can you specify the name of the journal @user2873476?